# React Native Customized Image Picker doesn't show gallery images on android

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I have to use a multiple picker in my react native application, and I tried to use this package: [react native customized image picker](https://github.com/shijingsh/react-native-customized-image-picker) with the next configuration:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
 multiple: true
}).then(images => {
 console.log(images);
});
```

On `iOS` is working great, I can see my photos when it opens the gallery and can select and show them, but on `android` I can only open the gallery but it doesn't show any photos.

I can switch between my gallery folders and as a folder thumbnail I can see a photos, it shows the number of photos for each folder, but when I open a folder, it's empty[image]

I also tried to use [react native image crop picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) which allows for `multiple selection` but it doesn't work on `android` and after i select a photo, it close the gallery modal.

`Does anyone encountered this?`

**Here is the issue opened on their GitHub:**

https://github.com/shijingsh/react-native-customized-image-picker/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please check your android manifest file for permission

**Add following permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Source** : https://github.com/shijingsh/react-native-customized-image-picker#android

Comment: Yes, i’ve added them, Both main manifest File and debug manifest File